# When user resumes app, how do I call another (loading) activity in the event that Android has killed and recreated my app?

Tags: android

**Issue at Hand**

I have a "LoadActivity" that I call at the beginning of my app to do a quick load of some data I need (into a singleton) for any of my activities.  Everything is working fine, except when Android kills and restarts the app from the background.  I've made an attempt at a solution, but (as explained below) it doesn't do the trick.

**Q:**
*When user resumes app, how do I call my LoadActivity if Android has killed and recreated my app?*

---

**Previous Attempt**

My attempted solution is as follows

In my app, in the start of any activity, I call the following:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    MyApplication.onStart(this);
    super.onStart();
}
```

Subsequently, MyApplication.onStart looks like this:

```
  public static void onStart(Context context){
    if(!Singleton.get(context).isReady())
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoadActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The issue is that Android continues the process of creating the activity, instead of interrupting that process to launch the LoadActivity intent.  I'm sure this is intended behavior, but that leads to an eventual null pointer error when it comes across a value of my singleton that is still null (since LoadActivity hasn't filled it in).  I need it to stop trying to load the current activity until after the LoadActivity has been executed.

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can do a `customIntent`. Something like this:

```
startActivity(getCustomIntent(LoadActivity.class));
```

before that will be your code.